Troubleshooting Model File Loading Issues
"I’m encountering this error in my PythonAnywhere application when trying to read my training files and use them in the final stage. I've repeatedly updated libraries and corrected paths, but the deployment still hasn’t succeeded. Could you help me?"
2024-11-04 21:12:35,262: Exception on /sonucum [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mypersonalityinventory/mysite/flask_app.py", line 1260, in sonucum
    genel_sonuc()
  File "/home/mypersonalityinventory/mysite/flask_app.py", line 792, in genel_sonuc
    model = joblib.load(lfk_model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 587, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 506, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
KeyError: 0


Please can you provide more context. Model files details, what you are using to load. Any code to accompany this error. Looks like a joblib error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

def genel_sonuc():
cinsiyet = session['gender']
model_path = '/home/mypersonalityinventory/mysite/LFK_model.pkl'
#değiştirildi
model_path1 = '/home/mypersonalityinventory/mysite/random_forest_model.pkl'

# Modelleri yükle
model = joblib.load(model_path)
model1 = joblib.load(model_path1)

